# Can you use await in promise' catch block of javascript?

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm getting an error in the following code, in the `await` part:

`SyntaxError: Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function (91:12)`

```
.catch((error) => {
      response.setOriginalResponse(error);
      this.logger.log(genericError, LEVEL_ERROR, error);

      if (error.hasOwnProperty('response')) {
        await error.response.json().then((data) => {
          response.setData(data);
          response.addError(parseErrorDescriptionFromResponseMessage(data.message));
        });
      } else {
        response.addError(genericError);
      }

      return response;
    });
```

The function is `async`

`async registerUser(username, email, password, provisionalToken)`

I am doing a fetch call inside.

Comment: Avoid mixing `.then()`/`.catch()` style with `async`/`await`, where you'd just use `try`/`catch`  blocks.

Answer (score 2):

The anonymous function you're using isn't async. Try below code.

```
.catch(async(error) => {
  response.setOriginalResponse(error);
  this.logger.log(genericError, LEVEL_ERROR, error);

  if (error.hasOwnProperty('response')) {
    await error.response.json().then((data) => {
      response.setData(data);
      response.addError(parseErrorDescriptionFromResponseMessage(data.message));
    });
  } else {
    response.addError(genericError);
  }

  return response;
});
```